# Chave estrangeira pode não ser chave primaria?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Sou nova em bancos de dados. Meu professor pediu que fizéssemos a ligação de 3 tabelas de filmes:

- `Titulos`, com nomes e link dos filmes
- `Categorias` do filme e link para os filmes
- Uma tabela do meio que ligaria categoria ao título do filme.

Então, a tabela do meio deve ter duas chaves primárias para as tabelas `Títulos` e `Categorias`.

O que ele quer:

Ele que quer o nosso BD permita a procura do filme pelo nome (título) e apareça a categoria ao mesmo tempo.

Qual será a minha chave estrangeira: o link do filme ou o nome? obs: a chave primária é o nome e não o link.

Posso ter uma chave estrangeira que não seja chave primária?

Comment: Julgo que não é boa ideia que a chave primária da tabela Títulos seja o nome. Primeiro porque é uma string depois por poder haver mais de um filme com o mesmo título.

Comment: qual e a necessidade da tabela meio ?

Comment: podemos ver o que vc tem ate agora ?

Comment: Up_One, coloquei la em baixo o que eu fiz. Obrigada por tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade o que está querendo fazer é uma ligação N para N entre 2 tabelas, o que já se sabe que não é possível, então é feito o truque de usar uma terceira tabela entre as 2 tabelas que conterá o Id E o de Id de outra, logo você teria algo assim:

```
TABELA TITULO:
IdTitulo inteiro CHAVE PRIMARIA,
Nome string,
Link string,

TABELA CATEGORIA:
IdCategoria inteiro CHAVE PRIMARIA,
Nome string,
Link string,

TABELA TITULO_CATEGORIA:
IdTituloCategoria inteiro CHAVE PRIMARIA,
IdTitulo inteiro CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA,
IdCategoria inteiro CHAVE ESTRANGEI
```

RA

Na Tabela temos os Id das tabelas Titulo e Categoria, as ligações serão assim:

```
Titulo  1---------------N TituloCategoria N-------------1 Categoria
```

Um exemplo de como uma ligação assim fica (as tabelas são diferentes mas o caso é idêntico ao seu):

[image: Exemplo]

Devo lembrar-lhe que toda chave estrangeira é uma chave primária também, e toda chave primária pode ser uma chave estrageira de outra tabela. Você não pode dizer que o nome do Titulo é uma chave estrangeira porque não é uma chave primária. Chaves primárias devem ser sempre **números inteiros**, a ferramenta de SGBD pode até permitir que seja uma `string` mas isso é completamente errado. Chaves primárias devem ser sempre valores que **nunca** irão se repetir ou passar perto de se repetir.

Comment: Isto está meio certo. Chaves primárias não necessariamente precisam ser números inteiros. Bastam ser valores que não se repetem, ou seja, que identificam um registro unicamente (ver teoria dos conjuntos).

Comment: Então, como eu disse "a ferramenta de SGBD pode até permitir que seja uma string mas isso é completamente errado". É possível, mas todo profissional sabe que a PK precisa ser um ID inteiro unico e de preferencia autoincrementado.

Comment: Errado novamente. Há várias abordagens, sendo uma delas com a tabela indexada por uma `string` com índice reverso, que não possui problema de performance (ao contrário do uso simples de `string`). Há também o uso de `UUIDs`, ou então `Guid`s, que são sequências de caracteres em hexadecimal que substituem os números inteiros, com a vantagem de não haver sequências ou `IDENTITIES` para o controle da geração das chaves primárias.

Comment: Chaves primárias não precisam ser necessariamente ser do tipo inteiro. A recomendação para chaves primárias é, quanto menor(a quantidade de caracteres) melhor.

Comment: Cigano, querer usar um GUID pra uma tabela que terá um numero astronomico de inserts não é nem um pouco viável, é que o Marcos Xavier disse, a recomendação é quanto menor  melhor. GUIDs é recomendado para casos bem especificos.Usar GUID tem as seguintes consequências:
O tipo de dados grandes aumenta o tamanho do índice clusterizado, o que pode afetar contrariamente as operações comuns, como junções. A geração não ordenada de GUIDs faz com que sejam inseridas linhas em locais aleatórios no índice clusterizado, o que pode afetar a E/S necessária para consultar a tabela subjacente.

Answer (score 3):

> Qual será a minha chave estrangeira: o link do filme ou o nome? obs: a chave primária é o nome e não o link.

A resposta certa, considerando os padrões e boas práticas de modelagem de bancos de dados é: nenhum deles.

O correto é que sua tabela associativa já faça essa ligação de chaves estrangeiras.

Um DDL do seu banco seria algo assim (não sei que tecnologia de banco de dados você usa, então estou usando algo próximo do SQL ANSI):

```
create table Titulos {
    TituloId int primary key auto increment,
    NomeTitulo varchar(255) not null
};

create table Categorias {
    CategoriaId int primary key auto increment,
    NomeCategoria varchar(255) not null
};

create table TitulosAssocCategorias {
    TitulosAssocCategoriasId int primary key auto increment,
    TituloId int not null,
    CategoriaId not null
};

alter table TitulosAssocCategorias 
add constraint TitulosAssocCategorias_Titulo_FK foreign key (TituloId) references Titulos (TituloId);

alter table TitulosAssocCategorias 
add constraint TitulosAssocCategorias_Categoria_FK foreign key (CategoriaId) references Categorias (CategoriaId);
```

Tendo isso, o seguinte `select` traz os dados juntos:

```
select tc.*, c.*, t.*
from TitulosAssocCategorias tc
inner join Categorias c on c.CategoriaId = tc.CategoriaId
inner join Titulos t on t.TituloId = tc.TituloId
where t.NomeTitulo like '%Título de um Filme%';
```

> Posso ter uma chave estrangeira que não seja uma chave primária?

Não. Uma chave estrangeira é necessariamente uma chave primária de outra tabela.

Comment: ta muito facil asim ! na boa !

Comment: nossa, muito obrigada mesmo. Eu consegui entender um pouco. rsr

Comment: @Andressa Gostou da resposta? Por favor, marque a resposta como aceita em benefício da comunidade (é o ícone em forma de V abaixo da pontuação da resposta). Obrigado!

Comment: Eu acredito que seria melhor você explicar a ela como fazer (nem que fosse com outros exemplos) do que já dar a resposta completa...isso não incentiva o aprendizado.